# using wikipedia api for fetching random articles my android app

Tags: android, json

It keeps stopping and in summary it shows java.lang.reflect.InvoactonTargetException....
JSONException: No value.....

M uusing this link
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=revisions%7Cimages&rvprop=content&grnlimit=10
[Mianctiviy code below]
private fun fetchdata() {
val url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allcategories&acprefix=List+of&formatversion=2&format=json"
val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
Response.Listener{
val imgJsonArray = it.getJSONArray("allcategories")
val itemarray = ArrayList()
for (i in 0 until imgJsonArray.length()) {
val imgJsonObject = imgJsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
val img = images(
imgJsonObject.getString("category"),

```
                    )
            itemarray.add(img)
        }
        madapter.update_img(itemarray)
    }, {
        Log.d("wkiki","something went wrong")
    })

     // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to S.O. Please post your code instead of images and most importantly your logcat where the error has been thrown. You should visit this once https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

your approach to get data and parse json is very old try modern libraries like:

For Http requests:

Retrofit: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Volley:https://developer.android.com/training/volley

and for json parsing:

Gson:https://github.com/google/gson

Moshi:https://github.com/square/moshi